# Why is it mandatory to have private Constructor inside a Singleton class

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is my singleton class for obtaining the database connection.

I have a question here: why it compulsory to have a private constructor inside a singleton class (as throughout my entire application I am calling this class only once) and as one instance of a class can be achieved using the static method?

Can this private constructor can be avoided, or is it mantadatory?

```
 public class ConnPoolFactory {
        private static DataSource dataSource;
        private static Connection connection;

        private ConnPoolFactory() {
            System.out.println(" ConnPoolFactory cons is called ");
        }

        public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

            try {

                if (connection == null) {
                    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
                    Context envContext = (Context) initContext
                            .lookup("java:/comp/env");
                    dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/Naresh");
                    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                } else {
                    return connection;
                }

            } catch (NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return connection;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers , but Why others will create instance of my Singleton class as it is my Application and i have full control of that ??

Comment: The same way as the others won't access your data if you don't declare it private: if you are the only developer working on the project and having full control over it, it's okay. But when the other developers would start in your project, they won't know that they are not allowed to create more instances of your class. And by the way, you can accidentally forget it yourself, too :)

Comment: BTW: This is not a singleton as you have to create one instance somewhere.  You have a utility class which must also have a private constructor.

Answer (score 20):

Otherwise everyone can create an instance of your class, so it's not a singleton any more. For a singleton by definition there can exist only one instance.

Comment: Why others will create instance of my Singleton class as it is my Application and i have full control of that ??

Comment: You never know what happens with your application some other day. The project can grow, and you'll get more developers in it. So as long as your project is really small, and you have full control over it, you can do it in whatever way you like, but as soon as the project gets more complicated, you need to enforce the rule: "singleton is unique".

Comment: @user1254422 - Most people work in teams with more than one person, so that's why they say "others".  However, even if it's just you, you can accidentally create more than one instance if you are not careful.  The private constructor is a safety mechanism that prevents multiple instances, since the only way to create an instance is through the static get method.

Comment: @user1254422: the same way, if you have full control over the project, you don't need to declare the data private, right? But as soon as the project gets bigger, you have to start enforcing the rules.

Answer (score 8):

If there no such a private constructor, Java will provide a default public one for you. Then you are able to call this constructor multiple times to create several instances. Then it is not a singleton class any more.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need lazy initiation:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
            return instance;
    }
}
```

is the best way, because is thread safe.

Answer (score 6):

The Singleton pattern typically includes a *non-public* constructor, for two reasons.  A constructor has to exist because if there's no constructor at all, a public default constructor is included.  If you have a public constructor, though, people can just make their own singletons at will (which someone inevitably will, meaning there can be more than one).

It doesn't have to be private, though.  In fact, as i heard it, the Singleton pattern as specified by the GoF mentions a *protected* constructor, for some odd reason.  Something about inheritance, i hear, but singletons and inheritance do not play well together at all anyway.

It's even possible to have a public constructor, as long as it can detect whether an instance already exists and throw an exception or something if it does.  That'd be enough to guarantee singleness.  But it's rather uncommon, because doing it that way complicates things by providing two apparent ways to acquire an instance -- only one of which will actually work.  If you don't want outside code to be able to create a second instance, why should a constructor be part of the public interface?

Answer (score 4):

For the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) you use an private constructor to ensure that no other instances can be created, otherwise it wouldn't be a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

A static class is different from a singleton in that a a singleton class enforces that there is always at most one instance.  A static class has no instances, and is just a bundle of static functions and static data.

So for a Singleton class, i.e. one with at most one instance, then a private constructor is required.

In your example, it looks like the Singleton class fits more than the static class- because of the connection and dataSource members.  Make those members private, your constructor private and provide static methods that reference a static ConnPoolFactory instance.  If instance is null, create a new one, otherwise just use it.

Answer (score 3):

For singletons and utilty classes you can use an `enum` which is a final class and implicitly defines a private constructor.

```
enum Singleton {
     INSTANCE
}
```

or

```
enum Utility {;

}
```

In your example above you have a utility class because you have no instance fields, methods and don't create an instance.

Answer (score 2):

The comment as you said that If I am complete owner of my application and I will never commit mistake of creating instance of singleton class directly using the public constructor but will use the static method for getting it. But in real world, often application switch hands between multiple developers. If the new developer is not aware that you want only one instance of the class in the application, he/she may accidently create another one by using the public constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It is mandatory. Your code may be fine, but others can use this code and instantiate another object, or you might do it by accident. This way is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton def:

> Ensure the only one object need to create for the entire main stack (per main class).

If you want to satisfy above statement then we should give constructor as a private. Actually through singleton we are getting ref not object that's why it is not mandatory then we can create object in other classes but we can't access reference (Constructor as public).

Ex:

```
public class SingleTon {

    private static SingleTon s;
    public SingleTon() {}

    public static SingleTon getInstance() {
        if (s == null) {
            s = new SingleTon();
            System.out.println("ho ho");
        } else{
            return s;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SingleTon s=SingleTon.getInstance();

        SingleTon s11=new SingleTon();
        SingleTon s12=new SingleTon();
        s11.getInstance();
        s12.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ho ho
```

Comment: It is not possible to create singleton with public constructor because it will create new instance. That defeats the purpose of singleton