# What does this private method do in this singleton Java class?

Tags: java, android, singleton

I've got a singleton class, which functions perfectly fine. I now just wonder what the last method is for?

```
public class PicassoSingleton {
    private static Picasso instance;

    public static Picasso with(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Picasso.Builder(context.getApplicationContext()).debugging(true).downloader(new ImageDownloader(context)).build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private PicassoSingleton() {
        throw new AssertionError("No instances.");
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what it does or what the use is?

Comment: You may find answer from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963667/why-is-it-mandatory-to-have-private-constructor-inside-a-singleton-class)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally it would be enough to make the constructor `private` to prevent others classes from instantiating a `PicassoSingleton`.

Throwing an exception in the private constructor seems to be paranoid programming, because the implementor of a class knows it's internal details and must know what he does.

But there is one reason when it makes sense. Throwing an exception in the constructor will also **prevent** others from using **reflection** to instantiate an object of the class.

This will be impossible

```
Constructor<PicassoSingleton> constructor = PicassoSingleton.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
constructor.setAccessible(true);
constructor.newInstance();  // will throw the AssertionError - impossible to instantiate it
```

Answer (score 3):

It prevents the class from being instantiated, if you have no constructor specified then all classes by default can have a new instance created using `new PicassoSingleton()` with no arguments.

If you specify a constructor and make it `private` then only the class itself can create instances of itself. If you then throw an exception inside the constructor not even the class can instantiate itself and it prevents people using reflection from doing so.

Doing this essentially means that the class can provide static methods, variables, etc but can never be used as an object (unless you provide another constructor, in which case the access levels of that constructor may allow it to be used).

Comment: This is not true. If you create a contractor that takes variables than you can't use the default constructor.

Comment: The code he listed didn't have another constructor. If there is another constructor then the same arguments about private, etc apply but this particular constructor is redundant.

Comment: Oh sorry got confused, unfortunately I can't change my vote unless the answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

That's the constructor for the `PicassoSingleton` class. It's private to make sure you can't call it from other code. Instead, you use the `with` method to obtain the singleton instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
private PicassoSingleton() {
    throw new AssertionError("No instances.");
}
```

Constructor is made private so that no new instances of the class can be created using new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`PicassoSingleton` is a constructor here and by making it private you are restricting other class to instantiate this.

This make the constructor unavailable to other classes and an instance of this class can only be accessed via getInstance method.

Answer (score 0):

In additional to Tim B answer I want to say that, not only that you prevent this class from been used as object, you also prevent other classes to extend it.

How ever you do not have to throw exception in the constructor you can just leave it blank, the only reason to do it is protection from your self.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Picasso with(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Picasso.Builder(context.getApplicationContext()).debugging(true).downloader(new ImageDownloader(context)).build();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

this method is use to access private field "instance" and it is static bcoz then you can directly access it with its class name without making objects. and it is a public method because you may need to access it from outside of the current package. initially it is check whether instance variable is null or not. if null, then it is not already initiated. then it will create a new Object and initiate it. and finally return the instance object reference. this kind of methods are called accessior methods in programming.

```
 private PicassoSingleton() {
    throw new AssertionError("No instances.");
}
```

this is the constructor of the PicassoSingleton class. according to theory of Singleton design pattern definition, it should not allow to make objects of the class. to do it we can make a private constructor. private modifier is access only within the same class. So at the developing time someone mistakenly create a instance to this class it will throw a Assertion Error by telling "No Instances"

hope you get what i mean.

finally one word about class field

```
private static Picasso instance;
```

this object reference variable is to hold the object reference. and it is private to limit the access from outside of the class. and it is static reference bocz it is access from static method.