# create a singleton class in java using public constructor

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor, singleton, public

Do I have to use private constructor to make a class singleton? Is there any other way than using private constructor?
Can't I make a class singleton using public constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it mandatory to have private Constructor inside a Singleton class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963667/why-is-it-mandatory-to-have-private-constructor-inside-a-singleton-class)

Comment: @ManikantaMani You may take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

If your class has a public constructor, then anybody can create an instance of it at any time. So it's not a singleton any more. For a singleton, there can exist only one instance.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it has to be a private constructor is because you want to prevent people from using it freely to create more than one instance.

A public constructor is possible only if you are able to detect an instance already exist and forbid a another instance being created.

> Is there no way other than using private constructor ? Can't we make a class singleton using public constructor ?

Yes, it is actually **possible**, for example:

```
class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    public Singleton() throws Exception    //Singleton with public constructor
    {
       if(instance != null)
          throw new Exception("Instance already exist");      
       //Else, do whatever..such as creating an instance
    }
}
```

Comment: **Remarks:** A standard singleton class will have private constructor and a getInstance() method. Assuming OP already know those things and is asking for possibilities of using public constructor, what was given will be what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

One way to create Singleton object using `public constructor` with `throw exception` from constructor if object is already exist.

**For Example:**

```
public class Singleton {

private static Singleton singleton;
private String hello;

public Singleton() throws Exception {
    if (singleton != null) {
        throw new Exception("Object already exist");
    }
}

public static Singleton getInstance() throws Exception {
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new Singleton();
    }
    return singleton;
}

public String getHello() {
    return hello;
}

public void setHello(String hello) {
    this.hello = hello;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Singleton single1 = Singleton.getInstance();
        single1.setHello("Hello");
        System.out.println(single1.getHello());

        Singleton single2 = Singleton.getInstance();
        System.out.println(single2.getHello());

        Singleton single3 = new Singleton();
        System.out.println(single3.getHello());


    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}

}
```

Comment: The key principle in your solution is exactly the same as what I have already provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you really must use public constructor, then you should check whether instance is null and throw an exception.

```
if(instance != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Singleton pattern is used when you should have exactly 1 object of a class (e.g. Factories are very often implemented as Singletons).

`public` modifier allows anyone to access your method (as well as your constructor). In that case, anyone can create an instance of your class, thus it won't be a singleton anymore.
By setting `private` modifier to your constructor, you are sure, it cannot be used outside of the class - no one will create any more objects of that class.

```
public class SingletonExample {
  private static final SingletonExample instance;

  // Initialize instance object in static block - done while loading the class by class loader
  static {
    instance = new SingletonExample();
  }

  private SingletonExample(){}

  public static SingletonExample getInstance(){
    return instance;
  }

  // Method used to create java.test.DateFormat using Oracle SQL Date pattern
  public DateFormat createDateFormat(String mask){
    if("DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS".equals(mask)){
      return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    } else if("DD-MM-YYYY".equals(mask)){
      return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported mask - " + mask);
    }
  }
}
```

And usage example

```
public class SingletonExampleTest{
  public static void main(String... args){
    java.util.Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SingletonExample singleton = SingletonExample.getInstance();
    String mask = "DD-MM-YYYY";
    DateFormat df = singleton.createDateFormat(mask);
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The private constructor is a reason, why your class is Singleton.

This [Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm) shows pretty well, how you can use your Singleton class by using `getInstance()`